# Why 2 css methods in jquery do not work one after another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove borders and make them reappear after a bit, but 2 css methods do not work one after another somehow.

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "border-left": "none",
      "border-bottom": "none"
    });

    var that = this;

    var returnBorder = window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(that).css({
        "border-left": "solid 3px #0086b3;",
        "border-bottom": "solid 3px #0086b3;"
      });
    }, 500);
  });
```

Comment: both css left and bottom will be executed at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "border-left": "none",
      "border-bottom": "none"
    });

    var that = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(that).css({
        "border-left": "solid 3px #0086b3",
        "border-bottom": "solid 3px #0086b3"
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='item' style='width: 100px; height:100px;display:block;border: solid 1px black'>
    test
    </div>
```

Problem in your code is, you have given `;` in applying css in js code, which js gives by default, so you dont need to give that.
I have removed it from my code.

Give it a try, this will work.

Comment: Oh God! I see! Thank you!

Comment: Your most welcome! If your problem has been solved by my answer, you can accept my answer !